# Android set button witdh to screen-width/2

Tags: android, xml, button

I want put 19 button in an activity like the app phone keyboard. I'm programming a simple calculator.

The buttons seem good from android studio xml preview, but when i run my app on device buttons has different size so the effect isn't correct. How can i take the same effect o device?

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Calcolatrice">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:id="@+id/virgola"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/uguale"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/uguale"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/virgola"
    android:onClick="virgola" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:id="@+id/uguale"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="@string/uguale"
    android:onClick="uguale" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/zero"
    android:id="@+id/zero"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/virgola"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/virgola"
    android:onClick="zero" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/piu"
    android:layout_above="@+id/uguale"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="@string/piu"
    android:onClick="piu" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tre"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/piu"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/piu"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zero"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/zero"
    android:text="@string/tre"
    android:onClick="tre" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/uno"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tre"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="@string/uno"
    android:onClick="uno" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/due"
    android:layout_above="@+id/virgola"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/virgola"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/virgola"
    android:text="@string/due"
    android:onClick="due"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/quattro"
    android:layout_above="@+id/uno"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="@string/quattro"
    android:onClick="quattro" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cinque"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/quattro"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/uno"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/uno"
    android:text="@string/cinque"
    android:onClick="cinque" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sei"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cinque"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/due"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/due"
    android:text="@string/sei"
    android:onClick="sei" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/meno"
    android:layout_above="@+id/piu"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sei"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sei"
    android:text="@string/meno"
    android:onClick="meno" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sette"
    android:layout_above="@+id/quattro"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="@string/sette"
    android:onClick="sette" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/otto"
    android:layout_above="@+id/quattro"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sette"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sette"
    android:text="@string/otto"
    android:onClick="otto" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nove"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sei"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cinque"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cinque"
    android:text="@string/nove"
    android:onClick="nove" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/per"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nove"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sei"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sei"
    android:text="@string/per"
    android:onClick="moltiplica" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cancella"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sette"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="@string/cancella"
    android:onClick="cancella" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/piuomeno"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cancella"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sette"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sette"
    android:text="@string/piuomeno"
    android:onClick="piuomeno" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/percento"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nove"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/otto"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/otto"
    android:text="@string/percento"
    android:onClick="percentuale" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/diviso"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/percento"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nove"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nove"
    android:text="@string/diviso"
    android:onClick="diviso" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/cancella"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/diviso"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/diviso"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Button for id zero must have the width=screen_width/2 and other must have the width=screen_width/4.

Comment: Use `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels` to get the device width, and define your view widths accordingly.

Comment: Please please please use a gridview!

Comment: i want obtain an effect like this http://www.applezein.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/iOS-7-vs-Android-4.3-9.jpg

Comment: Yes use a GridLayour/GridView!

Comment: but i can't have a button with different width like in the image in the link

Answer (score 0):

Try this  (Note : set appropriate id and text )
i used Linearlayout and `weight` property to set width

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:onClick="cancella" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:onClick="cancella" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:onClick="cancella" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:onClick="cancella" />

            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="cancella" />


        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```